# ng-repeat not updating when pushing new item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to update a view with ng-repeat after pushing a new item to the list, however ng-repeat still keeps the old reference. Here is my code
(function () {
    "use strict";

```
angular.module('messages', [])

.component('messages', {
    template: '<ng-outlet></ng-outlet>',
    $routeConfig: [
      { path: '/', name: 'MessageList', component: 'messageList', useAsDefault: true },
      { path: '/:id', name: 'MessageDetail', component: 'messageDetail' },
    ]
})

.component('messageList', {
    templateUrl: '/angular/spa/profile/components/messages/template/message-listing.template.html',
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["$http", messageListController],
})

.component('messageDetail', {
    templateUrl: '/angular/spa/profile/components/messages/template/message-detail.template.html',
    controllerAs: "model",
    bindings: { $router: '<' },
    controller: ["$http", messageDetailController],
})

.component('messageBubble', {
    templateUrl: '/angular/spa/profile/components/messages/template/message-bubble.template.html',
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["$http", messageBubbleController],
    bindings: {
        message: '<',
        user: '<'
    },
});

function messageBubbleController($http) {
    var model = this;
    model.$onInit = function () {
        model.currentUserId = $("#loggedInUserIdSignalR").val();
    };
}

function messageDetailController($http) {
    var model = this;
    model.item = null;
    model.user = null;
    model.message = null;
    model.loading = false;
    model.chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
    model.$onInit = function () {
        model.loading = true;
    };
    model.sendMessage = function () {
        if (model.message.length > 0) {
            console.log(model.messages.length);
            model.chatHub.server.send(model.message, model.user.SubjectId, model.item.ItemId);
        }
    };
    model.chatHub.client.broadcast = function (message, date, recipientId, itemId, senderId, senderNickName, senderPicture) {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            model.messages.push({
                ConnectionId: "",
                DateSent: "/Date(1468852585430)/",
                Message: message,
                Sender: senderId,
            });
        });
        console.log(model.messages.length);
        console.log('New incoming message: ' + name + " ->" + message)
    };

    this.$routerOnActivate = function (next) {
        var id = next.params.id;
        fetchConversationMessages($http, id).then(function (response) {
            model.loading = false;
            model.uid = response.uid;
            model.item = response.conversation;
            model.user = response.conversation.User;
            model.messages = response.conversation.messages;
        });
    };


    function fetchConversationMessages($http, id) {
        return $http.get("/profile/messages-data/" + id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        return response.data;
                    });
    }
}

function messageListController($http) {
    var model = this;
    model.conversations = []
    model.loading = false;
    model.$onInit = function () {
        model.loading = true;
        fetchConversations($http).then(function (conversations) {
            model.loading = false;
            model.conversations = conversations.results;
            console.log(model.conversations);
        });
    };

    model.$routerOnActivate = function (next) {
        console.log('messages list comp activated');
    }
    function fetchConversations($http) {
        return $http.get("/profile/conversationsData")
                    .then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
    }
}
```

})();

in this block of code

```
model.chatHub.client.broadcast = function (message,date,recipientId,itemId,senderId,senderNickName,senderPicture) {
            model.messages.push({
                ConnectionId: "",
                DateSent: "/Date(1468852585430)/",
                Message: message,
                Sender: senderId,
            });

            console.log(model.messages.length);
            console.log('New incoming message: ' + name + " ->" + message)
        };
```

Is where I get the new message and push it to the messages list, the console logs shows the updated list however I have on my template this

```
<div class="chat-room">
        <pre>{{model.messages.length}}</pre>
        <message-bubble ng-repeat="msg in model.messages" message="msg" user="model.user"></message-bubble>
    </div>
```

and this line of code

```
    <pre>{{model.messages.length}}</pre>
```

still shows the old list, I read in another post that this is happening because of references but I've tried to solve a lot different ways with no luck.

Comment: Do you need to trigger a digest/apply after updating the model?

Comment: I think that happens when I send another message, can you tell me how to manually trigger that?, I tried model.apply(), $scope.apply() and it says function not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everywhere where you push a new message, change:

```
model.chatHub.client.broadcast = function(...) {
            model.messages.push({
                ConnectionId: "",
                DateSent: "/Date(1468852585430)/",
                Message: message,
                Sender: senderId,
            });
        };
```

into:

```
model.chatHub.client.broadcast = function(...) {
       $scope.$apply(function() {
            model.messages.push({
                ConnectionId: "",
                DateSent: "/Date(1468852585430)/",
                Message: message,
                Sender: senderId,
            });
        });
    };
```

The other solution would be to find angularjs wrapper for your communication library.

What `$scope.$apply` do is basically it tells AngularJS that data used by your app changed and that it need to run
digest loop again. As you probably know digest loop checks what data changed and runs all `$watch`es for data that changed, some of them are used by directives like `ng-repeat` to update DOM.

Comment: I'm getting $scope is not defined, I tried $scope.$apply, $scope.apply, model.$apply, model.apply and no luck

Comment: I added the whole code for that module, perhaps you see something I don't

Comment: @JGEstevez you must inject `$scope` into your controller just like you injected `$http` service

Comment: Change `messageDetailController($http)` into `messageDetailController($scope, $http)` and `["$http", messageDetailController]` into `["$scope", "$http", messageDetailController]`